# Manipulating HTML dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

I have designed a webpage (which was a coding challenge from [FrontEndMentor](https://www.frontendmentor.io/challenges/interactive-pricing-component-t0m8PIyY8/hub/interactive-pricing-component-JX4A6XnLV)) and I have been working on the javascript for it. Below, you may find an image of the webpage itself[image]

My issue arises with the pricing slider. A 25% discount must be added when the switch is toggle. I have written the javascript to apply the discount to the prices but it will only change the price when I move the slider to another value (from $16 to another value and back to $16) to display the discount for, $16.00. I am trying to manipulate the DOM dynamically, as to, when the discount switch is toggled, the user should witness the discount added immediately.

I have attached my javascript and HTML code below. Any help would be appreciated.

```
const pageviews = ["10K PAGEVIEWS", "50K PAGEVIEWS", 
                    "100K PAGEVIEWS", "500K PAGEVIEWS", "1M PAGEVIEWS"];


// default prices 
let price = [8.00, 12.00, 16.00, 24.00, 36.00];
let i = 0;


const views = document.getElementById("view");
const prices = document.getElementById("demo");

// slider element
const slider = document.getElementById("sliderRange");

button = document.getElementById("buttonID");

// eventlistener to track if the user toggles the discount switch and applies and reverts
// the changes of the prices based on a "counter variable" i. The discount will be toggled if
// the switch is toggled an odd number of times, showing it has been toggled last instead of untoggled
button.addEventListener("click", function(){
        i++;
        if(i%2 !== 0){
            price = price.map((num) => {return num * 0.75;});
        }
        else if(i > 1 && i%2 === 0){
            price = price.map((num) => {return num / 0.75;});
        }
});

views.innerHTML = pageviews[2];
prices.innerHTML = price[2].toFixed(2);


//switch statement to process slider inputs
slider.oninput = function(){

    switch(parseFloat(this.value)){
        case 10.0:
            views.innerHTML = pageviews[0];
            prices.innerHTML = (price[0]).toFixed(2);
            break;

        case 32.5:
            views.innerHTML = pageviews[1];
            prices.innerHTML = (price[1]).toFixed(2);
            break;

        case 55.0:
            views.innerHTML = pageviews[2];
            prices.innerHTML = (price[2]).toFixed(2);
            break;

        case 77.5:
            views.innerHTML = pageviews[3];
            prices.innerHTML = (price[3]).toFixed(2);
            break;

        case 100.0:
            views.innerHTML = pageviews[4];
            prices.innerHTML = (price[4]).toFixed(2);
            break;

        default:
    }
}
```

HTML for slider and pricing

```
  <div class = "views-price">
    <p class = "views" id = "view"></p>
    <p class = "month" id = "months">
      <span id = "dollar">$</span>
      <span id = "demo"></span>
    /month</p>
  </div>

  <div class = "slider-class">
    <input type = "range" min = "10.0" max = "100" 
    value = "55.00" class = "slider" id = "sliderRange" step = "22.5">
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is because you are not updating the value of `prices` in your `button.addEventListener('click', function(){});` function. You are only changing the value of prices when you move the slider, so even if you click the button, it will not be updated until you move the slider again.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script>
window.addEventListener("load", (event) => {
  const pageviews = ["10K PAGEVIEWS", "50K PAGEVIEWS", 
                    "100K PAGEVIEWS", "500K PAGEVIEWS", "1M PAGEVIEWS"];


  // default prices 
  let price = [8.00, 12.00, 16.00, 24.00, 36.00];


  const views = document.getElementById("view");
  const prices = document.getElementById("demo");

  // slider element
  const slider = document.getElementById("sliderRange");

  //
  // eventlistener to track if the user toggles the discount switch:
  //
  document.getElementsByName("billingperiod")
  .forEach(function(item, idx) {
    item.addEventListener("change", function(){
        //
        // yearly:
        //
        if(this.value == 1) {
          price = price.map((num) => {return num * 0.75;});     
        //
        // monthly:
        //
        } else {
          price = price.map((num) => {return num / 0.75;});             
        }
    
        slider.oninput();
    });
  });

  views.innerHTML = pageviews[2];
  prices.innerHTML = price[2].toFixed(2);


  //switch statement to process slider inputs
  slider.oninput = function(){

    switch(parseFloat(this.value)){
        case 10.0:
            views.innerHTML = pageviews[0];
            prices.innerHTML = (price[0]).toFixed(2);
            break;

        case 32.5:
            views.innerHTML = pageviews[1];
            prices.innerHTML = (price[1]).toFixed(2);
            break;

        case 55.0:
            views.innerHTML = pageviews[2];
            prices.innerHTML = (price[2]).toFixed(2);
            break;

        case 77.5:
            views.innerHTML = pageviews[3];
            prices.innerHTML = (price[3]).toFixed(2);
            break;

        case 100.0:
            views.innerHTML = pageviews[4];
            prices.innerHTML = (price[4]).toFixed(2);
            break;

        default:
    }
  }
});
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class = "views-price">
    <p class = "views" id = "view"></p>
    <p class = "month" id = "months">
      <span id = "dollar">$</span>
      <span id = "demo"></span>
    /month</p>
  </div>

  <div class = "slider-class">
    <input type = "range" min = "10.0" max = "100" 
    value = "55.00" class = "slider" id = "sliderRange" step = "22.5">
  </div>

  Monthly <input type="radio" name="billingperiod" value="0" checked></input> 
  <input type="radio" name="billingperiod" value="1">Yearly</input> billing 25% discount

</body>
</html>
```

When one selects monthly/yearly radio, we run

```
slider.oninput();
```

to update infomation.

We use radio.onchange event in order to avoid bad toggling if user clicks quickly and continuously on the same radio button.

Comment: You shouldnt just hand developers the answer, you should explain what is wrong with their answer then explain how you resolve that and give examples.

Comment: Sometimes we can propose a solution as it is very near to the question...

Answer (score 0):

I'd make a function called `updatePrice`, that just updates the price. It should just access the price variable (or take it as a parameter) and apply it to the price tag. You should call this function every time you change the price in some way